# regarding finding a string in a given vector

Tags: r

Given a string, like `xyz`, and a string vector, like

```
abc
xyz
cde
fgh
xyz
```

Is there a function that can output the position of `xyz` in this vector, here it should be (2,5); as well as the number of occurrence, here it should be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
yourlist = c("abc", "xyz", "cde", "fgh", "xyz")
which(str_detect(yourlist, "xyz"))
```

This will return 2 and 5.

Comment: Is using an external package really needed for such a simple operation? What about just `which(yourlist == "xyz")` ?

Comment: @thelatemail You are totally right! Unless if you care about substring, for instance if "xyzz" contains "xyz", simple boolean operation will do the job.

Comment: `grep("xyz",yourlist)` in base R has you covered for the second case too. `str_detect` is essentially just a wrapper around `grepl` that is included with R.

Answer (score 0):

One other approach, with base R:

```
regmatches(yourlist, gregexpr(pattern = "xyz", text = yourlist,ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE))
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "xyz"

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
character(0)

[[5]]
[1] "xyz"
```

The output is longer, but it also confirm what was found ("xyz") and what locations